# Move a Range with offset

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a trouble by moving a designated row with an offset up.

It throws me the Error 424 that needs an Object.
I set up the rng2 with the selected range, but when i try to move it up, the error get in.

I basically need that when the area in the 87 row finds an empty cell delete it so the label with the info can go up.

Just

[image: this]

to

[image: this]

Thanks for your time!

```
    Sub RowOffset()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    'Worksheets("Mine").Activate

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C87:C37")
    Set rng2 = Range("C85:N85")


    With rng

        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

            If .Item(i) = "" Then

                rng2.Select
                rng2.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(-1, 0) 'THIS LINE HAS AN ERROR

            End If
        Next i
    End With

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `.offset()` a range that has been deleted before. Try this instead (not tested, I am answering on a smartphone):

```
With rng
    For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If .Item(i) = "" Then
           set tmp=rng2
           tmp.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
        Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(-1)
    Next i
End With
```

The `rng2.offset(-1)` (the second argument, 0, is optional) should not be inside the if-clause.

There is also no need to `.select` a range before deleting it. In fact, leaving this step out could improve the performance of your script.

**Edit**:
Well, as @Matto quite rightly remarked, my former solution still did not work. So I had another look at it and modified the whole sub as follows:

```
Sub rowOffset()
 Dim rng As Range, row As Range, i%
 Set rng = [c37:n85]
 For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
   Set row = rng.Rows.Item(i)
   If row.Range("a1") = "" Then row.Delete shift:=xlUp
 Next i
End Sub
```

I think this is shorter anyway ... and *it works* (tested).

Comment: I was trying something similar to answer this question and I got the same error.

Comment: There's still an error on the line Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(-1)
Says the same, "Requires an Object"

Comment: @cars10m, thank you for your edit, and yes, it solves the problem, but, when it reach to the "Componente" Row, it delete it, and it shouldn't.
But i'm trying to figure it out how to solve it.
Thank you so much!

Comment: I just noticed that I checked the wrong column to be empty! You need to check whether `row.Range("a1")` is empty instead of `"b1"`! Just changed it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code errors is because after `rng2.Delete ...` `rng2` no longer points to a valid range (because you just deleted it).

That said a better approach would be to first identify the range to delete, then delete it in one go.

Something like this (assumes your first data is in column B)

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        ' Find Total row
        '  assumes there is no other data below the table in Column B
        Set r2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(-2, 0)
        If IsEmpty(r2) Then
            ' Find the last row of data
            Set r1 = r2.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Range(r1, r2).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This line contains errors

Set r2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(-2, 0)

Error 1004

"Application-defined or Object-defined error" when selecting the range.

Comment: Did you check the assumptions I stated in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
Range(“C35”).End(xlDown).Offset(1,0)
```

will give you the first cell in the first row to delete.

Then

```
Range(“C35”).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Offset(-2,0)
```

Will give you the bottom right cell in the area that you want to delete.

So, set these two cells into variables (e.g. cell1 and cell2).
Then:

```
Range(cell1, cell2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

will land you at the result.